# How can I remove individual Google products?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

If I look at my Google dash board for my Google Apps admin account I see:

```
App Engine  - My Applications 
Calendar Calendar - Settings 
Checkout Checkout
Contacts Contacts
Custom Search Custom Search - My Search Engines 
Developer Consoles Developer Consoles
Docs Docs - Settings 
Gmail Gmail - Settings 
Subscribed Links Subscribed Links - My Subscribed Links 
Voice Voice
Webmaster Tools Webmaster Tools
```

How do I get rid of App Engine, Checkout, Custom Search, Developer Consoles, Subscribed Links, and Webmaster Tools?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer your question but with 'Google Apps for Business' you can turn off individual services through the Domain Administrator settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract from [Google Support](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81987)

> **Deleting: Other products**
>
> If you'd like to remove proucts from
>   your account, just follow these steps:
>
> - Sign in to your Google Account.
> - Visit the [My Account page](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount).
> - Click the Edit link located next to 'My products.'
> - Select the product you'd like to remove from your account.

Comment: You can't do that with all the products.  There is no delete or remove button.

Comment: @WiskyWilso: Well, then, you're stuck with using something like a Greasemonkey script to hide those options from yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, I think once you access a Google service, it's there indefinitely—in fact, on my Google Apps account, the "edit" link Barry mentions doesn't exist at all.

You didn't give your reason for wanting to remove services in your question. If it's just about account page cleanliness, just pretend the stuff isn't there—it really doesn't matter, and I don't think that page was meant to be used regularly. If you're worried about the information stored in the account, you might find the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/) useful for figuring out what information you need to remove.